# Communicating with content scripts without requesting "tabs" permission

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, privacy, userscripts

When developing a Chrome extension, my background script needs to communicate with the content scripts in the tabs loaded with a particular site.
Is there a way to communicate without using chrome.tabs.sendRequest?

This function requires the "tabs" permission which shows up as "this extension has access to your browsing history," which scares off users.

Comment: @serg is right, you don't need `tabs` permission if your communication is not complicated. What sort of information are you communicating?

Answer (score 4):

<s>Sorry, there is no other way around.</s>

**UPDATE**

Actually there is a way. Instead of pushing data from a background page to a content script you can pull data from a content script, and this doesn't require any permissions:

**content script:**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "getData"}, function(response) {
    console.log("data:", response);
});
```

**background page:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "getData") {
        sendResponse({param1: "value1", param2: "value2"});
    }
});
```

Comment: He is asking: "Is there a way to communicate **without** using chrome.tabs.sendRequest?"

Comment: @Derek So you see `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` somewhere in my answer? Plus he is more concerned about communicating without raising the tabs permission warning than this particular method. And as to your answer - injecting content script doesn't require tab permission if you do it through the manifest.

Comment: Injecting content script will show the same warning as the `tabs` permission.

Comment: @Derek It will show the same warning as `http://*/*` domain permission, not `tabs`. But it's not the point - you said injecting content scripts requires `tabs` permission, and I said this is true only if content scripts are not declared in the manifest.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution but it requires polling whereas I would prefer to have the background page trigger the communication.

Answer (score 1):

Remember even if you could communicate with background page without using `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` (actually it is almost [impossible](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication)), you still need the `tabs` permission in order to inject a content script.

Read more: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: There are two ways to inject scripts: one by declaration in the manifest, which doesn't require "tabs"; the other programmatically which does require "tabs".  Thanks for reminding me anyway; I do inject programmatically at one point anyway; so I have 2 reasons to use "tabs" right now.